# Why might some Android devices use vastly more graphics memory to run the same app?

Tags: android, memory, graphics, opengl-es

My GLES2.0 app is running out of memory on a YUREKA YU5510 running Android 5.1.1.

Profiling reveals that failure occurrs as the app passes 512mb heading into the first game.

However, profiling the exact same build on a Galaxy Note 5 showed the app using only 275mb at the same point in play.

Booting the app to the title screen on the YUREKA (and letting GC settle) shows 318.89mb in use total. On the Note 5 it shows 178.4mb.

Most memory regions (Java, Native, Stack, Code and Others) are very similar on both devices. However, graphics memory in use is 100mb higher on the YUREKA just on the title screen - and this discrepancy rises as I leave the title screen and head into the game proper, ultimately accounting for the whole of the 237mb difference.

The app loads exactly the same artwork and textures regardless of what device it runs on. The Note 5 has a higher native resolution than the YUREKA, so if anything it should be consuming more memory for screen buffers. We don't used packed textures - everything is straightforward RGBA8, so I wouldn't expect it to have to create multiple internal buffers.

Sorry I can't post a repro; it would be the entire app. Has anyone else experienced any kind of gotchas relating to RGBA8 textures on android?

EDIT: I finally got the YUREKA rooted over the weekend (so that I could install profiling tools). When I ran the exact same build of the app post-root, memory usage reported by Android Studio was ~150mb lower. So it looks very much as though some bloatware (malware?) installed on the stock device was responsible.

Comment: What dimensions are your textures? If you're not using power-of-two dimensions then some implementation might round-up to the next PoT. e.g. A 1025x1025 texture might take ~4MB on some devices and ~16MB on others.

Comment: Good catch, but all our textures are PoT (packed into atlases for that very reason to avoid that kind of nonsense)

Answer (score 0):

Whenever problem like this occurs , so below procedure to root cause
First check SFDump( to check the resolution differences)
then check adb shell dumpsys meminfo PID ( which u already checked)
then you can verify the breakup like which component is contributing for apps pss
adb shell cat /proc/PID/smaps ( this will give pretty much gud idea about the culprit) 
After this it depends which component is consuming accordingly can process ( either for native or java heap )